# Ошибка функции strcpy

Tags: c++, строки

начал изучать строки и появился вопрос:
При выполнение команды `strcpy` в Visual Studio возникает ошибка компиляции ибо это небезопасно использовать данную команду.Почему ее небезопасно использовать?И какая разница между `strcpy` и `strcpy_s` ?
PS.Прошу прошения если вопрос составлен плохо.

Comment: Очередные нападки M$ на posix в попытке переманить молодых и неопытных разработчиков

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не то чтобы опасно, просто надо обеспечить некоторые условия. Например

```
char s[5];
strcpy(s,"Hello, world");
```

и в результате в массив из пяти символов копируется 13 символов. Возникает проблема.

В VC++ это не ошибка, а предупреждение - что лучше б вам использовать версию, в которую вы должны передать еще и размер массива-приемника:

```
strcpy_s(s,5,"Hello, world");
```

и больше, чем указано, символов скопировано не будет.

VC++, кстати, сообщает о том, как заставить его не считать это проблемой - прочтите его сообщение полностью, и добавьте в код первой строкой

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Ну, или таки используйте `strcpy_s`...

Comment: Или `strlcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t dest_size)` из libbsd-dev

Comment: @avp Или [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) из стандарта :) Кстати, VC++ и на нее ругается и предлагает `strncpy_s`

Comment: Ну, алгоритм strncpy работает немного по другому. Если пересылаем 10 байт, а в src 5-й нулевой, то оставшиеся 4 в dst тоже будут прописаны нулями, а если в src в первых 10 байтах нуля нет, то и в dst он не появится. А strncpy_s вообще, если после ее выполнения dst (его размер задается в ней) не завершается нулем, вызовет "обработчик недопустимых параметров" (что это такое, не знаю)